# cordova.file.cacheDirectoryを消すにはどうすればよいか

Tags: javascript, monaca, cordova

現在Monacaを用いてアプリを作成しています。
CorvodaのFileプラグインは導入済みです。

[Monacaのドキュメント](https://docs.monaca.io/ja/reference/cordova_5.2/file/)によると、cordova.file.cacheDirectoryフォルダの
ファイルの削除は、本来であれば、アプリ側で制御すべき処理と書かれていますが、
削除する方法が書いていません。どのようにして削除すればよろしいでしょうか？

Comment: ドキュメントをざっと読む限りでは、普通にgetFileしてremoveしてという流れになると思いますが…何か特殊な削除方法があるのか、あるいは削除すべきタイミングがあるのか、といったご質問でしょうか？

Comment: 普通にgetFileしてremove(removeRecursively)するやり方の流れを教えて頂けないでしょうか？

Comment: ドキュメントに記載のある[こちらの記事](http://www.html5rocks.com/ja/tutorials/file/filesystem/)は読まれましたか?getFileしてからremoveするという基本的な流れについても書かれています。それでもまだわからないことがあるようでしたら、疑問点をより具体的に記すと回答もつきやすいかと思います。